# URL is changing unexpectedly in JQuery mobile

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile, data-url

I have a page like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/TekContent.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="ContentPage" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageIdContent" runat="Server">
    <div data-role="page" id="pageHome">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
            <h1>Welcome To My App</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li><a href="#pageSignMe">Sign me up</a></li>
                <li><a href="AddTag.aspx">Add Tag</a></li>
                <li><a href="ShowList.aspx">Tag List</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar" id="div2">
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

When I clicked on `Tag List`, url is changing from `http://localhost/MyApp/` to `http://localhost/MyApp/#AddTag.aspx` . I couldn't get why `#` adding to before Tag.aspx.

Later links are changing url more. Like: `http://localhost/MyApp/#MyApp/AddTag.aspx?id=1` this is because my page script inside AddTag.aspx isn't working properly.

I think I didn't get the JQuery mobile URL rules.

Comment: I think the problem may be in the master content. Can you post that as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URLs will be rewritten by jQuery Mobile. You should add the following to tell it that the link is *external*:

```
<li><a href="AddTag.aspx" rel="external">Add Tag</a></li>
```

See: [Page Links documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/pages/page-links.html)